# "For" loop Python code - does this look right/acceptable?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I would like to create a "for" loop (in Python 2). I have a list of obstacles and for each obstacle, if they are true (i.e. exist and appear in the list) I would like to append them to a list called "tests" and call a function called "obstacle_detection" (which deals with what happens when an obstacle is detected) (and I use "tests" later). This is part of a much larger program and I can't quite tell whether it's working, so I was wondering if anyone would be able to tell me if it makes sense? Or advise me of a better way there might be of doing this?

```
obstacles = [obstacle, obstacle1, obstacle2]
tests = []

counter = 0

for obstacle in obstacles:
    tests.append(0)
    tests[counter] = obstacle_detection(obstacle, pos)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: You can easily test if it's working by using another for loop to print out the contents of the array.

Comment: Have you seen https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? It might be a better fit for this question.

Comment: @JacobKrall aah thank you, I didn't know about this!

Comment: @Anna.H you would like to append `True` values of `counter` in `tests` list? You're appending 0 all the time: `tests.append(0)`

Comment: Using `enumerate`, will shorten your code.

Comment: @direprobs: `append` is only used to add an element to the list, which is then replaced by `obstacle_detection`.

Comment: [codereview.se] is not just a better fit -- this question is actually actively off-topic here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, noting the requirement of a *specific* programming problem in the first bullet point, and that an issue be *practical* and *answerable* (in the fourth). ("Answerable" means, in part, that there should be at least theoretically a complete and canonical answer possible, whereas "how can this be improved?" is by nature open-ended).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: No need for `enumerate` either.

Answer (score 2):

Your code possibly makes sense, depending on how you define `obstacles` and `obstacle_detection`.

As it is, you could write your code this way :

```
tests = [obstacle_detection(obstacle, pos) for obstacle in obstacles]
```

It creates a new list automatically, with the same length as `obstacles` and filled with `obstacle_detection` values for each `obstacle`.